# How to compare two dates using Android Room?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

### Summary

I'm making an Android app, and I have a Room entity called `Objective` which, among other things, stores its `startDate` and `endDate`.
I would like to make a query in which I can retrieve the "active" objectives, or in other words, the objectives which have already started, but haven't yet ended.

This is what I've got so far:

#### Query

```
@Dao
public interface ObjectiveDao {
    /* some code goes here... */

    /*
       For an objective to be active, its start date should be before the current day,
       and its end date should be after the current day.
    */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM objectives " +
            "WHERE end_date >= strftime('%s', 'now') + 0 " +
            "AND start_date <= strftime('%s', 'now') + 0")
    List<Objective> getActive();

    /* rest of the code goes here... */
}
```

### Problem

My problem lies in the fact that, when I call this method, an empty list is returned, instead of the expected list of active objectives
(at least this has happened in the various tests I've tried to run).

(See the edit at the bottom to see what was wrong with this problem.)

---

### Extra information

I will also include my `Entity`, `TypeConverter`, `RoomDatabase` and testing code just in case it can help you with anything.

#### Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "objectives")
public class Objective {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    
    /* 
        I feel like I don't need to 
        include the whole thing, just the part that matters.
    */
    
    @ColumnInfo(name = "start_date")
    private LocalDate startDate;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "end_date")
    private LocalDate endDate;

    public Objective() {
        this("", ObjectiveType.OBJECTIVE_DO, 0, LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().plusDays(1));
    }

    public Objective(String title, ObjectiveType type, int quantity, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
        this.title = title;
        this.type = type;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        id = 0;
    }

    /* rest of the code goes here...*/
}
```

#### TypeConverters

```
public class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    public static LocalDate fromTimestamp(Long value) {
        return value == null ? null : LocalDate.ofEpochDay(value);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long localDateToTimestamp(LocalDate date) {
        return date == null ? null : date.toEpochDay();
    }
    /* rest of the code goes here...*/
}
```

#### RoomDatabase

```
@Database(entities = {Objective.class}, version = 1)
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract ObjectiveDao getObjectiveDao();
}
```

#### Instrumented Test

```
class TestUtil {
    static Objective createObjective() {
        Objective objective = new Objective();
        objective.setTitle("Test Objective");
        objective.setType(ObjectiveType.OBJECTIVE_DO);
        objective.setQuantity(10);
        objective.setStartDate(LocalDate.now());
        objective.setEndDate(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1));

        return objective;
    }
}

public class ObjectivesInstrumentedTest {
    private ObjectiveDao objectiveDao;
    private AppDatabase db;

    @Before
    public void createDb() {
        Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class).build();
        objectiveDao = db.getObjectiveDao();
    }

    @After
    public void closeDb() throws IOException {
        db.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void objectiveIsInsertedIntoDatabase() {
        Objective objective = TestUtil.createObjective();
        /*
            id is set to 1 because, otherwise, Room automatically sets the ID to 1,
            and when the objects are compared they do not match. (a value of 0 counts as null).
        */
        objective.setId(1);
        objectiveDao.insert(objective);
        List<Objective> objectives = objectiveDao.getAll();
        assertThat(objectives.get(0), equalTo(objective));
    }

    @Test
    public void objectiveIsActive() {
        Objective objective = TestUtil.createObjective();
        objective.setId(1);
        objectiveDao.insert(objective);
        List<Objective> objectives = objectiveDao.getActive();
        assertThat(objectives.get(0), equalTo(objective));
    }
}
```

In case you want to know, the first test runs just fine, but I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when running the second one.

I hope you can help me solve this problem, and thank you in advance for taking the time to read through this and think about any possible solutions.

##### Edit

As @MikeT pointed out, I was storing these dates not as seconds, nor as unix timestamps, but as days elapsed since 1970-01-01.

Comment: What is the format of your dates in the table?

Comment: @forpas Dates are stored as Longs, (technically 8 byte long integers if I'm not mistaken), since Room does not allow to store "complex data" (in other words, it [doesn't support object references](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strftime's `%s` returns the date time in seconds, ofEpochDay returns the number of days since 1970-01-01. So you need to compare likewise.

I believe that you might be able to use :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM objectives " +
            "WHERE end_date >= CAST(strftime('%J','now') - strftime('%J','1970-01-01') AS INTEGER) " +
            "AND start_date <= CAST(strftime('%J','now') - strftime('%J','1970-01-01') AS INTEGER);")
```

based upon [strftime](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) but I'm unsure if there are discrepancies. I would suggest not storing the data in such an awkward format and storing it in a format that is recognised by SQLite as a datetime (as per the link below)

Comment: Thank you so much! The solution seems so obvious now, thanks for explaining what I was doing wrong. I tried storing the data in a simpler format, just as you said, but unless I've missed something I believe that [Room doesn't support object references](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data), so my only choice is to store primitive data types.

Comment: By simpler format I meant either long or string BUT not the number of days rather the datetime (unix timestamp (optionally dividing by 1000 to drop the milliseconds)) as long or a string such YYYY-MM-DD (with or without time HH:MM:SS). The reason being so that you don't have to convert/calculate between datetime bases (*the awkwardness*), which could result in differences due to how the adjustments e.g. for leap years/seconds are implemented. However, you are obviously on top of that.